# Flushing OLE clipboard renders data that is immediately destroyed

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, ole

I'm using OLE clipboard to be able to **render with delay** also elsewhere than just to the global memory (but currently only to the global memory). When my application is closing, it checks if the object known to be once put into the OLE clipboard is still there. If yes, the application flushes the OLE clipboard:

```
CComPtr<IDataObject> dataInClipboard;

void CImage::OnCloseDocument(){
    // document is being closed
    // - render data to clipboard
    if (::OleIsCurrentClipboard(dataInClipboard)==S_OK)
        ::OleFlushClipboard();
    // - base
    ...
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't function. Despite `OleFlushClipboard` invokes my implementation of `IDataObject::GetData` where the global memory is allocated, populated with data, and returned via `STGMEDIUM` structure, I don't see any data in the clipboard (below Nirsoft's [InsideClipboard](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html) app):

[image]

This is how I have implemented the `IDataObject` interface:

```
struct TPosInterval{
    long a; // start (incl.)
    long z; // end (excl.)

    inline long GetLength() const{ return z-a; }
};

class COleDataObject:public IDataObject{
    volatile ULONG nReferences;
    IStream &s; // the source document that is about to be closed
    const TPosInterval range; // the range of Bytes to copy from the source document
    struct{
        ULONG n;
        FORMATETC list[2];
        UINT tymedMask;

        void Add(UINT tymed){
            assert( n<ARRAYSIZE(list) );
            assert( (tymedMask&tymed)==0 );
            FORMATETC &r=list[n++];
                r.cfFormat=RegisterMyClipboardFormat();
                r.lindex=-1;
                r.tymed=tymed;
            tymedMask|=tymed;
        }
    } supportedFormats;
public:
    COleDataObject(IStream &s,const TPosInterval &range)
        : nReferences(1)
        , s(s) , range(range) {
        s.AddRef();
        ::ZeroMemory( &supportedFormats, sizeof(supportedFormats) );
        supportedFormats.Add(TYMED_HGLOBAL); // global data to be rendered upon later request, e.g. OleFlushClipboard
    }
    virtual ~COleDataObject(){
        s.Release();
    }

    // IUnknown methods
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() override{
        return ::InterlockedIncrement(&nReferences);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() override{
        if (const auto n=::InterlockedDecrement(&nReferences))
            return n;
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid,PVOID *ppvObject) override{
        static const QITAB qit[]={
            QITABENT( COleDataObject, IDataObject ),
            { 0 },
        };
        return ::QISearch( this, qit, riid, ppvObject );
    }

    // IDataObject methods
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetData(LPFORMATETC pFormatEtc,LPSTGMEDIUM outMedium) override{
        const HRESULT hResult=QueryGetData(pFormatEtc);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
            return hResult;
        if (!outMedium)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        ::ZeroMemory( outMedium, sizeof(*outMedium) );
        auto nBytesToRead=range.GetLength();
        switch ( outMedium->tymed=pFormatEtc->tymed ){
            case TYMED_HGLOBAL:
                if (HGLOBAL hMem=::GlobalAlloc( GMEM_SHARE|GMEM_MOVEABLE, nBytesToRead )){
                    if (const PBYTE pData=(PBYTE)::GlobalLock(hMem)){
                        const CInstance::TContent f=&s; // a helper class that facilitates access to IStream
                        PBYTE p=pData; f.Seek(range.a);
                        while (nBytesToRead>0)
                            if (const auto nBytesRead=f.Read( p, nBytesToRead ))
                                p+=nBytesRead, nBytesToRead-=nBytesRead;
                            else
                                break;
                        ::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                        if (nBytesToRead>0) // failure during reading?
                            if (const HGLOBAL hRealloc=::GlobalReAlloc( hMem, p-pData, 0 ))
                                hMem=hRealloc;
                            else{
                                ::GlobalFree( hMem );
                                return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                            }
                        outMedium->hGlobal=hMem;
                        return S_OK;
                    }
                    break;
                }else
                    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
        return E_UNEXPECTED; // we shouldn't end up here!
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetDataHere(LPFORMATETC pformatetc,LPSTGMEDIUM pmedium) override{
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryGetData(LPFORMATETC pFormatEtc) override{
        if (!pFormatEtc)
            return DV_E_FORMATETC;
        if (pFormatEtc->lindex!=-1)
            return DV_E_LINDEX;
        if (pFormatEtc->cfFormat!=RegisterMyClipboardFormat())
            return DV_E_FORMATETC;
        if ((pFormatEtc->tymed&supportedFormats.tymedMask)==0)
            return DV_E_TYMED;
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCanonicalFormatEtc(LPFORMATETC pFormatEtcIn,LPFORMATETC pFormatEtcOut) override{
        const HRESULT hResult=QueryGetData(pFormatEtcIn);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
            return hResult;
        if (!pFormatEtcOut)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        ( *pFormatEtcOut=*pFormatEtcIn ).ptd=nullptr; // target-device (ptd) for server metafile format is not supported
        return DATA_S_SAMEFORMATETC;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetData(LPFORMATETC pFormatEtc,LPSTGMEDIUM pMedium,BOOL fRelease) override{
        return E_UNEXPECTED; // construct another IDataObject to change the source Stream!
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumFormatEtc(DWORD dwDirection,IEnumFORMATETC **ppEnumFormatEtc) override{
        if (dwDirection!=DATADIR_GET)
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        if (!ppEnumFormatEtc)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        return ::SHCreateStdEnumFmtEtc( supportedFormats.n, supportedFormats.list, ppEnumFormatEtc );
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DAdvise(LPFORMATETC pFormatEtc,DWORD advf,LPADVISESINK pAdvSink,DWORD *pdwConnection) override{
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DUnadvise(DWORD dwConnection) override{
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumDAdvise(IEnumSTATDATA **ppenumAdvise) override{
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: Properly implementing `IDataObject` is more difficult that one thinks, but you don't have to do this (you shouldn't) as the Shell provides one, just do `SHCreateDataObject(NULL, 0, IntPtr, NULL, riid, ppv)`. At least you'll be able to compare behaviors.

Comment: Regrettably I get the same result even if I "wrap" my `COleDataObject` with the one provided by `SHCreateDataObject` :-(

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"? You shouldn't use a custom IDataObject implementation at all (ie: drop your COleDataObject)

Comment: Well, but how do I then render with delay my data? I thought the fourth `pdtInner` parameter served for any customizations of the shell default data object. On the other side, if I already had the data rendered, then there would be no question in using the default shell data object. (Btw, I think I'm now struggling with a detail in my implementation - for if I refresh Nirsoft's InsideClipboard BEFORE calling `OleFlushClipboard`, then the data is rendered correctly and I can see "Memory" under the "Handle Type" column.)

Comment: What do you mean by "render with delay" in the fist place, I don't see the concept of "delay" in your implementation? An IDataObject must contain memory blocks (HGLOBAL) which is a "static" storage (it must be in the IDataObject beforehand), or IStream if you want to serve data on-demand. Maybe you're looking for IStream formats? For all possible legitimate needs, the Shell implementation should suffice.

Comment: Well, I'm sticking to Jeff Procises' book _Programming Windows with MFC_ (but not using MFC at this particular moment) where there is an example of delayed rendering with global memory and the text says, "One detail to be aware of when you use COleDataSource delayed rendering is that if the storage type is TYMED_HGLOBAL, TYMED_ISTREAM (…) the storage medium might be allocated before OnRenderData is called. (…) If lpStgMedium->tymed is TYMED_NULL, OnRenderData is responsible for allocating the storage medium." I think there's another catch in my constellation of affairs... :-/

Answer (score -1):

The following line was missing. With it present, `OleFlushClipboard` hands over the global memory handle, created in my `GetData` method, to the system, instead of destroying it. The data thus exist even after the document has been closed or the application has been shut down.

```
    struct{
        ULONG n;
        FORMATETC list[2];
        UINT tymedMask;

        void Add(UINT tymed){
            assert( n<ARRAYSIZE(list) );
            assert( (tymedMask&tymed)==0 );
            FORMATETC &r=list[n++];
                r.cfFormat=IInstance::GetClipboardFormat();
/* -------> */  r.dwAspect=DVASPECT_CONTENT;
                r.lindex=-1;
                r.tymed=tymed;
            tymedMask|=tymed;
        }
    } supportedFormats;
```